# Blazor | Blazorize | RadioGroup \ Radio: Re-render page elements after updating the data context

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazorize

```
@switch(currentQuestion.Question.Type)
            {
                case AnswerToQuestionType.OneAnswer:
                    <Column ColumnSize="ColumnSize.Is12">
                        <Field>
                            <FieldLabel>Выберите один ответ</FieldLabel>
                            <RadioGroup TValue="string" Name="oneanswer" CheckedValue="selectedOneAnswer" CheckedValueChanged="OnSingleModeSelectAnswerChanhe">
                                @foreach (var a in currentQuestion.Question.Answers)
                                {
                                    <Radio TValue="string" Value="a.Id.ToString()" Checked="false">@a.Text</Radio>
                                    <br />
                                }
                            </RadioGroup>
                        </Field>
                    </Column>
                break;
    >other code<
            }
```

the code above is part of the user testing page. After choosing an answer and moving on to the next question, the choice is saved (see screenshots). How to fix this so that after moving on to the next question, no option is selected?

[option chosen independently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV6ug.png)

[the next question with the ALREADY BECKED option (the same as the selected answer in the previous step)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmfxa.png)

Answer (score 1):

oh my god ..... The solution turned out to be extremely simple - I reset selectedOneAnswer in the wrong place ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).